# TexStudio PDF viewer moves page down on mouse click - can I turn this off?

Tags: texstudio, viewers

When I click on the pdfviewer page, the page scrolls to the next page.  This didn't use to happen, and I would like to turn it off.

The movement to the next page happens with both the left and right mouse buttons (which is unhelpful when I want to 'go to source'), and it happens whether or not the viewer page is embedded or popped out.

Answer (score 7):

There's a decent solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/943051/241489):

> In the viewer, choose Window > Show > Toolbar. On the toolbar, you can toggle the zoom button or the hand button. Either way disables the click=nextpage behavior, restoring the desired ctrl-click behavior.

Once you've done this, the click-scrolling appears to remain disabled even as you close/reopen TeXstudio.